# DotNetOpenAuth Get Facebook Email Address

Tags: facebook, dotnetopenauth

I have the following code where its grabbing First/Last name.  I realize that email is an extended permission, but what would I need to modify to request extended permissions?

How do I get the email of an authenticated Facebook user through the `DotNetOpenAuth`?

```asp
        fbClient = new FacebookClient
        {
            ClientIdentifier = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebookAppID"],
            ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebookAppSecret"],
        };

        IAuthorizationState authorization = fbClient.ProcessUserAuthorization();
        if (authorization == null)
        {
            // Kick off authorization request
            fbClient.RequestUserAuthorization();

        }
        else
        {
            var request = WebRequest.Create("https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(authorization.AccessToken));
            using (var response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    var graph = FacebookGraph.Deserialize(responseStream);

                    // unique id for facebook based on their ID
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("fb-" + graph.Id, true);

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
                }
            }
        }

        return View("LogOn");
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add the following bits:

```asp
            var scope = new List<string>();
            scope.Add("email");
            fbClient.RequestUserAuthorization(scope);
```

Comment: yep - scope are facebook permissions

Comment: Note that in newer version of DotNetOpenAuth.ApplicationBlock, ClientSecret doesn't exist. It should now be as follows: FacebookClient fbClient = new FacebookClient
            {
                ClientIdentifier = "appId",
                ClientCredentialApplicator = ClientCredentialApplicator.PostParameter("appSecret")
            };

Answer (score 1):

If you are using VS2012 built in oauth providers you just need to update your oauth package. See the last post on the following link: http://forums.asp.net/t/1847724.aspx/1. The only email I can't retrieve is MS Live. Currently I use facebook, google, and yahoo.