# Simple asp.net Facebook authentication sample

Tags: asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I've read tons of documentation about Facebook authentication, but anything seems to work.

I've tried everything, including Facebook C# SDK, and many other options.

My application is an asp.net 4.0 web site (outside facebook).

Does anyone have an working sample?
All i need is to authenticate a user and get basic user information such as name, surname, email and picture.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/ which is very good. You can also use facebook api javascript library which is very easy to use. Maybe you haven't configured your application in facebook correctly. It needs callback url. Some related questions:

[Facebook/ Twitter with dotnetopenauth?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821747/facebook-twitter-with-dotnetopenauth)

[DotNetOpenAuth Get Facebook Email Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356409/dotnetopenauth-get-facebook-email-address)

[How to log in with Facebook using DotNetOpenAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164740/how-to-log-in-with-facebook-using-dotnetopenauth)